# Сортировка подсчетом на Си

Tags: c, алгоритм, cs50

Прохожу курс CS50 по основам Computer Science. На данный момент нужно реализовать сортировку подсчетом. С Си я познакомился совсем недавно, поэтому у меня возникают проблемы с(как мне тут кажется) изменением списков.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX = 65536;

void sort(int values[], int n);

int main()
{
    int a[] = {10, 0, 75, 43, 15, 25, 2, 27, 43};
    sort(a, 9);
    // for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) вот тут!
    // {
    //     printf("%d ", a[i]);
    // }
}

void sort(int values[], int n) // по условию задачи я не могу изменять обьявление функции
{
    // TODO: implement a sorting algorithm
    int counter[MAX];

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++)
    {
        counter[i] = 0;

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        counter[values[i]]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < counter[i]; j++)
        {
            values[j] = i;
            // printf("%d\n", values[j]);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Если я, например, распечатаю каждый символ в последнем цикле, который собственно и производит расстановку в нужном порядке, то получится то, что и должно получиться:

```
~/workspace/pset3/ $ ./counting_sort                                                                                                            
0
2
10
15
25
27
43
43
75
```

Значит, он все такие сортирует. Однако, когда я пытаюсь распечатать в мэйн функции список после применения функции получается странно:

```
~/workspace/pset3/ $ ./counting_sort
75
43
75
43
15
25
2
27
```

Не могу понять как такое происходит и где.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы начинаете каждый раз перезапись `values` с нуля. Сделайте так:

```
int currentPos = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < counter[i]; j++)
    {
        values[currentPos++] = i;
        // printf("%d\n", values[j]);
    }
}
```

Т.е. разделите текущую позицию и счетчик символов и идите все дальше и дальше.

Еще вариант - без новой переменной, но с изменением `counter` - все равно после выхода из функции он не нужен:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < MAX - 1; i++)
{
    while(counter[i])
    {
        values[j++] = i;
        --counter[i];
        // printf("%d\n", values[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А почему я начинаю перезапись с нуля? Мне это непонятно:(

Comment: `for(int j = 0; ...` - вот поэтому. Вы для каждого нового `counter` инициализируете `j` нулем - и начинаете писать в `values[j]`.